# Importing pyspark for standalone application

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning to use Spark. I followed [this](https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/getting-started-with-spark-in-python?utm_content=bufferd80a3&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) article till now. When I am trying to import pyspark I get the following error. There is a file accumulators.py in pyspark.

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "E:\\spark-1.2.0"
>>> sys.path.append("E:\\spark-1.2.0\\python")
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "E:\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pyspark.java_gateway import launch_gateway
  File "E:\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 26, in <module>
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
ImportError: No module named py4j.java_gateway
>>> sys.path.append("E:\\spark-1.2.0\\python\\build")
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "E:\spark-1.2.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
ImportError: cannot import name accumulators
```

How can I resolve this error? I use `windows 7 and java-8`. python version is `Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit)`

Comment: Can you print the value of `sys.path` after your appends?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue following the same article and was able to to fix it by changing the 00-pyspark-setup.py script to add the SPARK_HOME/python/lib path to python's sys.path instead of the SPARK_HOME/python directly.

My full 00-pyspark-startup.py script is now as follows:

```
import os
import sys

# Configure the environment
#if 'SPARK_HOME' not in os.environ:
#    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/srv/spark'

# Create a variable for our root path
SPARK_HOME = os.environ['SPARK_HOME']

# Add the PySpark/py4j to the Python Path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(SPARK_HOME, "python", "lib"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(SPARK_HOME, "python"))
```

Comment: thanks, but I got another error `No module named py4j.protocol`

Comment: then I tried to add the `python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip` file into PATH, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding E:\spark-1.2.0\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip to your PYTHONPATH